# NodeJS Request not returning

Tags: http, node.js, twitter, request, asynccallback

Pretty new to Node, and I'm trying to implement a twitter stream into my node/express app.

This file is inside a separate stream.js file inside my routes folder, and it's called via ajax from a client side jquery script.

I've looked and compared the http.request on several other sites and I've tried multiple configurations but nothing is budging. Everything up to http.request callback fires, but I can't get a response

```
    var http = require('http')
      , events = require('events')
      , url = require('url')
      , fs = require('fs')
      , path = require('path')
      , sys = require('sys')

      , tweet_emitter = new events.EventEmitter()
      , options = {
                host: "api.twitter.com",
                port: 80,
                path: "/1/statuses/public_timeline.json",
                method: "GET"
      }

    var getTweets = function() {
        console.log('getTweets');// fires fine
        var req = http.request( options, function( res ) {
            console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);// nothing here executes
            console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));

            var data = "";

            res.setEncoding('utf8');
            res.on('data',function( chunk ) {
                data += chunk;
                console.log(chunk);
            });

            res.on('end',function() {
                var tweets = JSON.parse( data );
                if( tweets.length ) tweet_emitter.emit( 'tweets', tweets )
            })

            req.end()
        });

        req.on('error', function(e) {
            console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
        })
    }

    setInterval(getTweets, 5000 );

    exports.stream = function(req, res){
        var listener = tweet_emitter.addListener("tweets", function( tweets ) {
            res.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type" : "text/plain" });
            res.write( JSON.stringify(tweets) );
            res.end();

            clearTimeout(timeout);
        });

        var timeout = setTimeout(function() {
            res.writeHead( 200, { "Content-Type" : "text/plain" });
            res.write(JSON.stringify([]));
            res.end();

            tweet_emitter.removeListener(listener);
        },10000);
    };
```

Comment: I don't see the problem, but I can offer my experience on this - it is not worth directly working with the built-in http.request object - the api is just too low level with too many things that can go wrong.  Use a request library like https://npmjs.org/package/request

Comment: That did it, really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I second Steve's comment. So many starting NodeJS developers hack their way on very low level methods that have been built by giants. Check out some of the more common libraries available on NPM.

Consider: https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/modules
or: https://npmjs.org/

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

Wow. Four years later. I am having a similar issue.

Agree with Steve's comment that maybe a better library..., but here is a solution for this library. Well, not *exactly* this library but the concept should work just as well.

Problem

```
const request = require('request');
var opts = {url:my_url,timeout:5000}
request(opts,function(error,response,body){
  var data = parse(response);
  dosomething(data);
);
// the callback is never called...
// even after the timeout period...
```

https://github.com/request/request

The doc says about `timeout` that `if the underlying TCP connection cannot be established, the OS-wide TCP connection timeout will overrule the timeout option (the default in Linux can be anywhere from 20-120 seconds).`

maybe I just couldn't wait 120 seconds? hmm...

To force the timeout I propose this solution:

```
const request = require('request');
var opts = {url:my_url,timeout:5000}
var complete = false
request(opts,function(e,r,b){
  if(!complete) {
    complete = true;
    var d = parse(r);
    dosomething(d);
  }
});

setTimeout(function() {
  if(!complete) {
    complete = true;
    dosomething(null);
  }
}, opts.timeout);
```

The root cause of my situation may have been that my ip was supposed to be whitelisted but I think it was blacklisted and the server is not responding at all, not even with an error. I am able to access it from a different ip, just not the ip which was requested for whitelist :)

The symptom became that my proxy exhibited an extraordinary amount of wait time that I did not previously anticipate because I had not experienced the issue at the time of development/test.